# MVC: Custom type declared in model or view?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

Trying to wrap my head around proper MVC theory and I'm a bit stumped when it comes to where a custom type is declared, in the model or the view.

I have a control panel where a bunch of model parameters are controlled my custom sliders.

```
// the (simplified) model

class RGParameter {
    var value: Int
    var name: String
    var type: SliderType
}
```

I made a custom slider that shows a different track image depending on the type of slider it is.

```
class RGSlider: UISlider {
    var type: SliderType {
        didSet{
             changeTrackImage()
        }
    }

    func init(frameRect: CGRect, theType: SliderType) {
    }

    func changeTrackImage() {
        var image: UIImage

        switch(type) {
            case .Hue: image = hueImage
            case .Sat: image = satImage
            // etc
        }
        // put image in track
    }

}
```

And somewhere, I need to have this:

```
 enum SliderType {
    case Hue
    case Sat
    case Lum
    case Brightness
    case Contrast
}
```

If I put the SliderType definition in the model, the slider UI won't compile by itself, and if I put the SliderType definition in the slider, the model won't compile by itself. At this point, I'm trying to work on model and view separately.

I'm missing something basic...

BTW, even though this is mostly a conceptual question, I tagged Swift because that's what I'm using and thought that maybe there might be an elegant Swift way of doing this.

Comment: A down arrow with no reason for an honest question? Seriously?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with having a type that's included by both the model and the view, particularly an enum which is effectively part of the vocabulary of your app. They both know about "integer", right? `SliderType` is just an app-specific version of that.

If you do that, though, you might want to remove the word "slider" from its name and make it more generic, like `VisualParameterType`. Put it into its own header file and include it in both places so they can communicate semantically.

Comment: After doing a little reading on MVVM, I'm starting to think that what I'm looking for is a View Model. My Model shouldn't know what kind of slider it needs, but the View Model should. So if I clean out anything display/view related in my Model, it should go into a View Model class that acts as the bridge between the Model and the View, keep the Model class cleaner.